# Multiple linear regression - drop only the missing value and not the entire row- Python

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I have a dependent variable and many different independent variable. 
In one of the column of the independent variable I have many value with zero or let's suppose "missing value".
Now, when I perform the Multiple regression, the model will be affected by the zero and if it is a missing value the model will remove the entire row. What I would like is that the model doesn't consider this variable if it is a zero value or missing value but still keep the other independent variable to predict the model.

Here is the example of the multiple linear regression:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

fit = ols('Wage ~ C(Sex_male) + C(Job) + Age', data=df).fit() 

fit.summary()

                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                   Wage   R-squared:                       0.592
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.048
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     1.089
Date:                Wed, 06 Jun 2018   Prob (F-statistic):              0.492
Time:                        22:35:43   Log-Likelihood:                -104.59
No. Observations:                   8   AIC:                             219.2
Df Residuals:                       3   BIC:                             219.6
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=======================================================================================
                          coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             3.67e+05   3.22e+05      1.141      0.337   -6.57e+05    1.39e+06
C(Sex_male)[T.1]     2.083e+05   1.39e+05      1.498      0.231   -2.34e+05    6.51e+05
C(Job)[T.Assistant] -2.167e+05   1.77e+05     -1.223      0.309    -7.8e+05    3.47e+05
C(Job)[T.Professor] -9273.0556   1.61e+05     -0.058      0.958   -5.21e+05    5.03e+05
Age                 -3823.7419   6850.345     -0.558      0.616   -2.56e+04     1.8e+04
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.479   Durbin-Watson:                   1.620
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.787   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.464
Skew:                          -0.108   Prob(JB):                        0.793
Kurtosis:                       1.839   Cond. No.                         215.
==============================================================================
```

Let's suppose there is a missing value in Age, then the Wage will be predicted by the other independent variables (C(Sex_male) + C(Job) etc.)
At the the number of observations will remain the same : 8. The missing value in the row will be "forgotten"

Is there a function that exists to perform it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a problem with code you're running?If so, please add your code in accordance with the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, your question reads like a statistics question.

Comment: I know it is possible to do it, the question is more if there is a function that exists to perform such a model? Or something I should add to my multiple linear regression?

Comment: In that case, it would make it clearer what you're trying to do if you posted the code you're using to create the multiple linear regression model, as well as a sample of your dataset.

Comment: Yes sure. I will do it :)

Comment: `will be predicted by the other independent variables`: You will need to estimate a second model for this. Using the parameters estimated with all variables will not be appropriate when using only a subset of variables in prediction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the model to consider variables that have missing values or values that equal zero, just drop those models from the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

# Drop variables with missing values
dataset_clean.dropna(axis = 1, inplace = True)

# Drop variables with values of zero
dataset_clean = dataset_clean.loc[:, ~(dataset_clean == 0).any()]
```

Then plug the new dataframe into your model.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will remove all the columns with zero on it :(